# wpf Can i display images in DocumentViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, documentviewer

I want to display xps Image in DocumentViewer, but without success.

Does DocumentViewer support displaying images?

If it is possible to display a picture in DocumentView, how can I do it?

Any reply will be helpful.

My code is as follows:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <FlowDocumentReader Height="150" Width="170">
        <FlowDocument  Name="flowDocument"   ColumnWidth="400" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Georgia">
            <Paragraph>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\XpsTest-main\XpsTest-main\33.jpg" Width="200" Height="200" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Foreground="Red" />
                </Grid>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentReader>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="save"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Content="show"/>
    </StackPanel>
       
    <DocumentViewer Name="viewer" Width="600"/>
</StackPanel>
```

#### C#

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Printing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Xps;
using System.Windows.Xps.Packaging;
using System.Windows.Xps.Serialization;

namespace XpsTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void PrintVisual(Visual visual)
        {
            PrintDocumentImageableArea imageArea = null;
            XpsDocumentWriter xpdw = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(ref imageArea);
            if (xpdw != null)
            {
                xpdw.Write(visual);
            }
        }
        public static void SaveAsXps(string path, FlowDocument document)
        {
            using (var package = Package.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(package, System.IO.Packaging.CompressionOption.Maximum))
                {
                    var xpsSerializationManager = new XpsSerializationManager(new XpsPackagingPolicy(xpsDocument), false);
                    var documentPaginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)document).DocumentPaginator;
                    xpsSerializationManager.SaveAsXaml(documentPaginator);
                }
            }
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SaveAsXps(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\temp.xps", flowDocument);
        }
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\temp.xps", FileAccess.Read);
            FixedDocumentSequence fds = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
            viewer.Document = fds;
        }
    }
}
```

Test the above code, the picture cannot be displayed normally in DocumentView.

Comment: Please supply a minimal reproduction of your issue. Make it easy for people to reproduce your issue. Most will not open a repo BTW.   You read the above?  Why are you not using your flowdocument directly?

Comment: Is that printing code even relevent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the exact same code to test in .NetFramework 4.8 and in .NET6 respectively. It doesn't show pictures in .NetFramework 4.8 and shows pictures in .NET6(.NET5).

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="80" Click="Button_Click_1">save as xps</Button>
     <FlowDocumentReader Height="150" Width="170" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
         <FlowDocument  Name="flowDocument"   ColumnWidth="400" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Georgia">
             <Paragraph>
                 <Grid>
                     <Image Source="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\WpfApp3\45.jpg" Width="200" Height="300" />
                     <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Foreground="Red" />
                 </Grid>
             </Paragraph>
         </FlowDocument>
     </FlowDocumentReader>
     <Button Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="80" Click="Button_Click">open xps file</Button>
     <DocumentViewer Name="viewer"  Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Codebehind:

```
public static void SaveAsXps(string path, FlowDocument document)
{
    using (var package = Package.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(package, System.IO.Packaging.CompressionOption.Maximum))
        {
            var xpsSerializationManager = new XpsSerializationManager(new XpsPackagingPolicy(xpsDocument), false);
            var documentPaginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)document).DocumentPaginator;
            xpsSerializationManager.SaveAsXaml(documentPaginator);
        }
    }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    { 
        string sFileName = @"C:\...\printPreview.xps";

        XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(sFileName, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        viewer.Document = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
        return;
    }
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveAsXps(@"C:\...\printPreview.xps", flowDocument);
}
```

The result in .NetFramework 4.8 :
[image]
The result in .NET6(.NET5) :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**This is caused by an security update from Windows**

**[KB5022083 Change in how WPF-based applications render XPS documents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb5022083-change-in-how-wpf-based-applications-render-xps-documents-a4ae4fa4-bc58-4c37-acdd-5eebc4e34556)**

*XPS documents ... .  Additionally, some inline images may not display correctly when XPS documents are loaded into WPF-based readers.*

*This regression was introduced in the December 13, 2022, cumulative security updates for .NET and .NET Framework.*

*Microsoft is actively investigating an additional update which restores compatibility while also resolving the underlying security issue.*

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is likely to be because Image is a UI control.
You could try putting it in a blockUIcontainer.
Try:

```
        <FlowDocument  Name="flowDocument"   ColumnWidth="400" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Georgia">
            <Paragraph>
               <BlockUIContainer>
                    <Image Source="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\XpsTest-main\XpsTest-main\33.jpg" Width="200" Height="200" />
               </BlockUIContainer>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
```

I am doubtful about textblock as well. That should probably be a run or paragraph.